# cython-gsl library wrapper

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I want to use the interpolation function from gnu library can someone suggest me how can i do it.Here is what i have been trying.

```
 import numpy as np
 cdef extern from "gsl/gsl_spline.h":
 int gsl_spline_init(gsl_spline * spline, const double xa[], const double ya[], size_t size)
 def cs(gsl_spline * spline,xa = np.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) ,ya = np.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) , int size):   
 s = gsl_spline_init(gsl_spline * spline, dnp.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) xa, np.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) ya, int size)
 return s
```

but while building the file i get following error.

```
 def cs(gsl_spline * spline,xa = np.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) ,ya = np.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) , int size):   
s = gsl_spline_init(gsl_spline * spline, dnp.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) xa, np.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1) ya, int size)                                  ^


testone.pyx:14:75: Expected ')', found 'xa'
building 'pang' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes    -fPIC -I/home/sulabh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/sulabh/include/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c testone.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/testone.o
testone.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here.
I'll give you some ideas on where to start.

First, you are placing your type declarations in a function call.
They should go in a function signature.
The error you are seeing comes because putting the type declarations in the function call is not proper syntax.

Next, you are using parentheses in your type declarations for the NumPy arrays that are passed as arguments to your functions.
You should use square braces.
For example, you have `dnp.ndarray(double_t ,ndim=1)`.
This should be something like `np.ndarray[double,ndim=1]` (the exact name depends on how you have cimported the ndarray class).

For cleaner declarations of types, you may want to consider Cython's [typed memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).